# `this` inside a function that isn't a prototype of a class

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a class without prototypes. Here is an example:

```
test = (function() {
  this.value = 1;
  this.print = function() {
    console.log(this.value);
  };
  return this;
})();
```

This works perfectly as intended. What I don't understand is `this.value` inside the `this.print` function. How does `this.print` correctly know that any mention of `this` refers to `test` and not `window`? Would any function defined via `this.___ = function(){}` automatically have `this` added as a context?

Comment: [Private members in JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html) -- read this.

Comment: for anyone who uses coffeescript like me, you can "close over the `this` variable` like in http://stackoverflow.com/a/10965498/927092 by using `=>` instead of `->` in your function declarations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`this` *always*<sup>1</sup> evaluates to the object upon *which* the function-object was invoked. It will evaluate to `window` if it was "invoked upon nothing" (or is a property of `window`).

(Note that `this` *is not* a variable and is thus *not* closed-over in a closure! This is why sometimes closures are needed to get the "correct" `this` which is often known by the variable `self` or `that` or `_this`.)

For example:

```
function f () { return this; }
var a = {f: f}
var b = {f: f}
a.f() === a     // true
b.f() === b     // true
f() === window  // true
```

---

An example of using a *variable* to create a binding to the current (as of when the enclosing function was invoked) `this`:

```
test = (function() {
  var self = this // <-- variable, which is "closed over"
  this.value = 1; // self === this
  this.print = function() {
    console.log(self.value); // <-- self "names" previous this object
  };
  return this;
})();
```

---

<sup>1</sup> This is a little lie. The `Function.call` and `Function.apply` functions allow specifying the `this` context and can be used by "context binding" functions such as [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to eliminate the need for an explicit "self closure" as shown above.

Comment: So the way I wrote it, if I did `_print = test.print; _print()`, it will still correctly print `1` because I defined it inside a closure. Is that correct?

Comment: No, inside *that* `_print` invocation `this` evaluates to `window` so it would be `window.value`. `this` is *not* a variable and is thus *not* closed-over in a closure. Using `test.print()` would have `this` evaluate to `test` and thus use `test.value`, which would be expected.

Comment: So there's no benefit of doing `test = (function(){...})();` vs. `test = {value: 1, print: ...}`? Either way I would have to prefix the function with `test`.

Comment: There is, *if* closing over a *variable* in the closure ;-)

Comment: I don't know what that means :)